# What to do in cases of unnecessary revisions

Tags: discussion, revisions

After a question has been edited, it jumps to the top of the list of questions in the home page. So to make your question 'permanently' stick there, all you have to do is constantly edit it with 'unhelpful' characters and sentences.

The reason am raising this issue is because of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427531/usb-3-0-coping-with-slow-speed-on-ubuntu-as-opposed-to-windows). If you look at its [revisions](https://askubuntu.com/posts/427531/revisions) you will see that the person who asked it has been editing unnecessarily.

**EDIT 1:** Bolded some words
**EDIT 2:** Added: `Is there anybody to solve my problem??`
**EDIT 3:** Removed: `Is there anybody to solve my problem??`
**EDIT 4:** Added: `?`

What can be done in such cases?

Comment: Well, sometimes the user simply sees room for improvement, and doesn't consciously aim at bumping their own question. I think it's good manners to try improve the quality of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag it. Explain the situation.

Mods will talk to the person doing the editing to try and calm them down. Some people just don't understand the problem of too much editing.

Comment: I did that @Oli.

Comment: And I've contacted the user.

Comment: Aha, I see. I must say I tend to edit more than once myself, sometimes seemingly small changes, but always found the fact that the post (or answer) was "lifted" as an undesirable side effect. I will limit it though

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't worry too much. After 10 revisions by a certain user, the post is converted to a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/232872) post.

This causes the original owner of the post to not earn any more reputation from that post, to counter the fact that it's been bumped too many times.